# Proper questions and proper information

Tags: discussion

1. Lots of people provide next to zero information about the issues they are having which makes helping them impossible and also wastes everyone's time because such questions need to be clarified.

   Consider this question: [Not recognized screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669549/not-recognized-screen) - there's zero information in it. "I have this problem" - that's it.

   What do people here think of having our own version of [http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) which will be shown to everyone who attempts to ask a question?
2. Another issue I have with particularly unix.SE is that lost of people avoid attaching pertinent logs because *"For dmesg and Xorg logs, it's way too long, I've to wait for it to happen to cut precise moment where it happened*".

   What about having our own alternative of e.g. pastebin.com or something?
3. Lastly, lots of people have issues with particular applications/deamons/services or their entire systems. It would be great to have some sort of community updateable document where we teach/show people how to extract logs, e.g. by using `dmesg`, `journalctl`, files in `/var/log/` or using utilities like `top`, `free`, `vmstat`, etc. It's maddening to see all the posts about someone's system being unstable/crashing/freezing and asking each time to post the relevant log files.

This is not a question per se. It's a call for action.

Comment: Not a new thing: [Why do we reward users for answering bad questions and would it be a good idea to incentivize those who downvote or flag them instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411512/why-do-we-reward-users-for-answering-bad-questions-and-would-it-be-a-good-idea-t). It's a tragedy of the commons: enlightened individuals could choose to downvote and close instead of answering, but they probably can't be united and fast enough to prevent the unenlightened individuals from answering first, resulting in bad questions being enough for the askers...

Comment: Good luck with sticking the idea of interfering more with the question asking process  down the throats of the SE powers that be. This is a relatively new development, IIRC, but it doesn't go nearly far enough: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucu9D.png  Some of this was briefly discussed in chat a day or two ago, around https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59159076#59159076

Comment: I address low-information posts by using well-written (IMHO) canned answers. I have "answers" about using `journalctl` (system "freeze", system "crash", network), "`cron` jobs", adding info in comments (don't), ... Anything where new users ask poor questions, and I know the answer, or any answer or comment that I reuse, like "Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu."

Comment: @waltinator, you should be marking them as duplicates instead... Shouldn't be much more hard to do that vs. copypasting a ready answer, but has the advantage that the dup target can have a more verbose explanation, without that having to be copied everywhere...

Comment: @waltinator mad kudos to you :-)

Comment: @ikkachu I do Close("End of Life"), AND use my canned comment because many low reputation users won't see 1 Close vote.